# Template Recognition in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, template-matching

So, I have been working on a **python** project in computer vision, but was stuck, as most of the tutorials that I found on the idea of template recognition, were rather on the idea of template matching, which assumes that the template is already present in the image. 
Some of the links, that I referred to are:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/
https://www.javatpoint.com/opencv-template-matching

I was really looking for someone's help who can point me in the correct direction as to what is the best way for template recognition amongst a range of multiple templates, which might or might not be present in the input image rather than template matching, which always assumes that the template is present in the input image